# Is there a way to pass a directory of saved docker tarballs to the Anchore inline scan?

Tags: docker, security, inline

I have a directory with a number of tarballs resultant from a `docker save` on a bunch of containers. Is there a way to pass this directory to the Anchore inline scanning tool to have it scan all of the saved containers in that directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the -v flag followed by the directory that contains your tarballs.
Here is an example from Anchore [blog](https://anchore.com/blog/inline-scanning-with-anchore-engine/):

```
cd example1/
docker build -t example1:latest .
cd ../example2
docker build -t example2:latest .
cd ..
mkdir images/
docker save example1:latest -o images/example1+latest.tar
docker save example2:latest -o images/example2+latest.tar
curl -s https://ci-tools.anchore.io/inline_scan-v0.6.0 | bash -s -- -v ./images -t 500
```